# how to do audio time-stretching in Android without using any native api

Tags: android, audio

I have been trying to find out a way on internet to do audio time stretching in Android unfortunately found nothing. There are some API like Sonic, SoundStrech written in C/C++ available however to use them good amount of C\C++ understanding is required. Also I am not sure if those can be used in paid applications. 
Well my question is; is there really no way to do sound stretching in Android purely without using any native API? If there is any could you please mention that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer for you, but a caution to stop you from making my mistake. 
I am quite new to android and java and I am also surprised, that there doesn't seem to be a solution in pure java either by use of maybe soundpool or audiotrack.

I thought I had found the solution with aocate presto sound library. It is very easy to implement, but there is two problems:

- Users of your application will also have to pay 6$ for use of the sound library in addition to the cost of your app.
- As I understand the comments (or maybe I didn't understand it correctly) it needs to verify the license for every use, which means that it only works with internet connection.

I am now trying to follow this tutorial: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/ and hoping it will help a noob get his feet wet with ndk using SoundTouch: http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/. This also has it's limitations as some have mentioned, that it is not supported in ICS. I have read, that the OpenSL ES had an update on Jelly Bean, so it may be working again. Could someone maybe verify or correct me?

Comment: Thanks for heads up.
I also thought of using SoundTouch library but it is released under LGPL license so not feasible to be used in paid applications.